# Confused about the definition of odd numbers...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So to put it simply, I am confused about the quantifier's role in the definition of odd numbers.

What I have always used is the form of:

Odd $= 2k+1$ for some $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

Even $= 2k$ for some $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

But my friend proposes this question to me...
Is it not true that ALL integers can be placed for the arbitrary $k$ to satisfy the definition of odds and evens?

That's when I realized, wait have I been using the wrong form all the time? What is the true quantifier to describe the $k$ in the $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Notice that @csch2 has placed the quantifier where it is best: before any condition. Putting quantifiers at the end can easily lead to ambiguity and imprecision.

Comment: @Lubin i see thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is odd if and only if there exists $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n=2k+1$. With logical quantifiers:
$$n\in\mathbb{Z}\text{ is odd}\iff\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}:n=2k+1$$
Similarly, $n$ is even if and only if there exists $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n=2k$. The integer $k$ is not arbitrary and depends on $n$ - we cannot just arbitrarily choose $k$ to satisfy the even or odd definition.

Comment: yes this is more precise, thank you